# Objective-C read Hex code and output Emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji

I have emoji codes (i.e. Unicode Hex codes) such as U0001f618. I want to be able to enter the code and return the emoji. So far this works:

```
NSLog (@"\U0001f618");
```

This returns the emoji, however if I store the code in a file and import it into an NSString and call;

```
NSLog (unicodeForEmoji);
```

The code is returned i.e.: \U0001f618, any ideas?

Thanks

D

Comment: You need to scan the text and replace appropriate escape sequences with the equivalent character.

Comment: In addition to the other issues, understand that NSLog often does not render non-ASCII characters correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytes are  unicode encoding:`NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding`.

To read directly from a file use:

```
NSString *unicodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Test:

```
// The next two lines substiture to reading the data from the file:  
unsigned char unicode32Chars[4] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0xf6, 0x18 };
NSData *unicode32Data = [NSData dataWithBytes:unicode32Chars length:4];
NSLog (@"unicode32Data: '%@'", unicode32Data);

NSString *unicode32String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicode32Data encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog (@"unicode32String: '%@'", unicode32String);
```

Output:

```
unicodeData: '<0001f618>'  
unicodeString: ''
```

I suspect you might really want to use UTF-8 encoding but that is a different byte string:

```
unsigned char unicode8Chars[4] = { 0xf0, 0x9f, 0x98, 0x98 };
NSData *unicode8Data = [NSData dataWithBytes:unicode8Chars length:4];
NSLog (@"unicode8Data: '%@'", unicode8Data);

NSString *unicode8String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unicode8Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"unicode8String: '%@'", unicode8String);
```

Output:

```
unicode8Data: '<f09f9898>'  
unicode8String: ''
```